# Why microstripline is compulsory to generate high frequency signal in the range of 2 Ghz or more

Tags: wifi, signal-theory

I would like to understand why the UHF (Ultra High Frequency) band in the range of 1 Ghz or more like 2.4 Ghz or 2.6 Ghz require microstripline to generate such signal frequency?

Is there any alternative that we can use that is readily available without microstripline?

Comment: Microstrip and Stripline are two different, albeit related, things. They are not required to generate Microwave band signals. Rather they are used to route these signals from the mixer part of an RF Tx front end (which will convert our tx signal from baseband to the desired Tx frequency) to the Antenna. This is required because signals at these frequencies act as electromagnetic waves and have properties that can be ignored at lower frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Well you really want some sort of controlled impedance, and Microstrip or Stripline based design (different things!) is the way to get there on a PCB.

You could use coax cables soldered in place, or even (rather large, but it is done) waveguide based systems, you usually see this one in things like radars and plasma heating systems where the peak power is high enough to make burning the substrate or arcing a problem.

As the frequency rises the length of a connection over which you can consider both ends to be equivalent falls (Generally about 1/8th of a wavelength at the highest frequency of interest), so by the time you hit UHF or low microwave the traces on the PCB start to act as components in their own right.